# Apply the homework tag during routine editing?

Tags: discussion, tagging, editing, homework

When editing a new question, for grammar, punctuation, clarity, formulas, etc., is it appropriate to add the homework tag if your intuition is strong that it is homework?

Please don't knee-jerk brand this a duplicate question.  This is a specific question about **homework tags** and **non-OP editing** that I didn't see directly addressed in the voluminous (I read more than ten) questions on [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/111/60679) ... [roiling](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/429/60679) ... [subject](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3838/60679).

I have been **assuming no**, that it's not constructive to force-apply the homework tag without asking the OP first, even for questions that I would bet 100:1 are homework.  I don't want to make the OP feel shame at asking a homework question, nor for asking one and neglecting to tag it as such.  Good [point by Isaac](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/914/can-we-please-stop-asking-is-this-homework/923#923) about the delicate etiquette of this.

What I'd rather is the OP see a friendly "We have the impression this is homework, and so we assume you would prefer help to a thorough answer. Please explain if not the case."

Or even a convenient, affirming, OP-knows-best prompt:

> Is your question homework?
>
> - Yes, I prefer answers not be too thorough.
> - No, I prefer detailed, complete answers.

But in lieu of a feature like that, I have been just refraining. What's your policy?

---

Edit: duplicates found at

- [Proper use of the (homework) tag redux](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8608/60679)
- [Proper use of Homework Tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3838/60679)

In particular from [Alex Becker's answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3840/60679):

> I and many other users consider it inappropriate to tag another user's question as homework unless they have explicitly said it is homework.

So now what I think I should do is propose a feature in meta that the OP can be offered a friendly prompt like the above.

Comment: Can I brand this a duplicate question if my knee is not jerking? http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8608/

Comment: Yes!  Thanks @RahulNarain I do think this issue is already well covered by [Brian M. Scott](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8608/60679)'s question and [rar](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3838/60679)'s question.  Glad to feel in tune with the zeitgeist.  

So, can I brand my own question a duplicate or does that require your rarefied powers?

Comment: We also have a [comment template](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4927#4927) about homework questions.